# logged-in user’s information in contact for 7 plugin

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, contact-form

I have 2 users in WordPress. One is admin and another is a contributor.

I am trying to send email using the `contact form 7` plugin.

I logged in by contributor user. I need to send user (contributor) details like `email`. I use a code `default:user_display_name` and `[email* your-email default:user_email]` in message body field. Both of them are not useful.

If I use `[_site_admin_email]` email of admin is sent. I want to send the logged-in user email.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `wpcf7_before_send_mail` action hook to add user's info in your email body. Below is an example on how you can do that.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body' );

function wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body($contact_form){
 $form_id = $contact_form->posted_data['_wpcf7']; // Get for ID 
 if ($form_id == 123): // 123 => Your Form ID.
     $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); // Get Current User Object
     $user_email = $current_user->user_email;

     // get mail property
     $mail = $contact_form->prop( 'mail' ); // returns array 

     // add content to email body
     $mail['body'] .= 'User Email Address: ';
     $mail['body'] .= $user_email;


     // set mail property with changed value(s)
     $contact_form->set_properties( array( 'mail' => $mail ) );
 endif;
}
```